# Converting between &str formatted like a unicode escape sequence into a char

Tags: string, rust, unicode, type-conversion, char

Is there any way to convert a &str formatted like a unicode escape sequence into a char (ideally without using an external crate)?

e.g. `"\\u{00e1}": &str` -> `'\u{00e1}': char`

Comment: I don't think there's a quick and easy way in the standard library. There are some external crates like [unescaper](https://lib.rs/crates/unescaper). Otherwise you'll likely need to parse out the codepoint and use `char::from_u32`. If that's what you want, edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: Is this a sequence within a larger string, or just the sequence itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert a Unicode escape sequence from a string to a character like any other *ordinary* character:

```
let s: &str = "\u{00e1}";
assert!(s.chars().next().unwrap() == '\u{00e1}');
```